# How to select radio button using button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically im creating an online voting system, i used radio buttons as identifier of which candidate is being voted. By the way, candidates are from my database.
This is the html code:

```
        <td align="center">
        <input type="hidden" id="myhidden" value="Independent">
        <button class="ind">Independent</button></td>
        <td align="center">
        <input type="hidden" id="myhidden2" value="Liberal Partylist">
        <button class="lp">Liberal Partylist</button></td>
        <td align="center">
        <input type="hidden" id="myhidden3" value="UNO">
        <button class="uno">UNO</button></td>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.ind').click(function() {
    $('input[id="' + $("#myhidden").val() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });

    $('.lp').click(function() {
    $('input[id="' + $("#myhidden2").val() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });

    $('.uno').click(function() {
    $('input[id="' + $("#myhidden3").val() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

This is working but only on first click, i want it to loop whenever i clicked on 'Independent' button `.ind`, 'Love Partylist' button `.lp` and 'UNO' `.uno` it will select all the members of the selected party list (one click vote). Im wondering why it is only working only on first click, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't specify what you mean by 'only working on first click'. What is/is not happening on second click? You may be clear on the behaviour you expect, but you have to tell us or we are just guessing.

Comment: can you please paste html code also, to solve other easily

Comment: @PhilipSmith here's whats happening: on first click i am able to choose the whole independent party list using the button, and then if i clicked on love party list it is also working fine, but when i clicked again on independent. The radio buttons are stucked on love party list.

Comment: @whoami it was too long. sir but let me try to update my question

Answer (score 0):

radio buttons, or option buttons as they are referred to these days, are designed so that only one is selected at any time. Clicking one should deselect all others.

If you are allowing multiple entries you should really be using checkboxes instead.

When you programatically set checked on a radio button you have to programatically remove it.

in each of your event handlers remove the checked attribute from the lists that you don't want selected as well as setting the attribute on the list you do want selected.

Comment: Your radio inputs has to have a name attribute value of which has to be unique for all radio inputs, now your buttons acting kinda like checkboxes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio.

Comment: No, i am not allowing multiple entries. One entry for each position (eg. president, vp and so on). i also tried to programmatically deselect the buttons using `.attr('checked', false)` but still no luck

Comment: If the radio buttons where given the name attribute the problem would get worse. Only one would be selected at anytime.

Comment: @PhilipSmith i have edited my comment please check. i really need this thanks

Comment: The html wasn't in the question before. The question talks about lists not single entries, It sounded like there were multiple entries for each party. Adding the same value to the name attribute for each radio button, will ensure that only one is selected at any one time.

Comment: So radio button os exactly for that, select one and only one from options,

Comment: @PhilipSmith each position has their own name attribute(same for each position), and only one can be chosen. i was looking for a one-click vote (from president down to escort of the whole partylist).

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev Yes.

Comment: Oh, nevermind guys i've got it working using .prop() instead of .attr(). anyways thanks for your time!